# Мати чи бути? "У мене є" чи "я маю"?

Tags: росіянізм, калька

Чи правда, що вирази із дієсловом *бути* на зразок "***є** й **у мене** сім пар голубів*" є непитомими для української мови і являють собою російські кальки, через що не мають бути вживані?

Замість виразу *"у когось є щось"* пропонується вживати лише "*мати*" у відповідній формі.

Comment: Повязані (?): [Is _у мене є_ equivalent to *я маю*?](/q/1160/585), [У мене (є) vs я маю в певному місці/в певний час](/q/2616/585).

Comment: так, усі питання пов'язані. Мені було досить цікаво це, але чомусь я не міг ніяк знайти, щоб хтось саме це спитав. Навіть при написанні в колонці "Similar Questions" не виднілися вами вказані. Підкажіть, що я маю робити в такому разі?

Comment: Якщо гинші питання збіжні з тим, чого хотѣв са́ме ти, тоді можеш видалити своє питаннє кнопкою [delete]. Можливо хочеш уточнити щось, тобто змінити питаннє, тоді є кнопка [edit].

Answer (score 1):

"Я маю" більш властиве іншим слов'янським мовам. "У мене є" дійсно запозичено з російської. Але це не значить, що "в мене є" - це неправильно. [Приклади вживання в літературі](https://slovnyk.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1292).

> - "У мене є просьба до тебе, Стехо" / Т. Шевченко "Назар Стодоля"
> - "Та в мене ще шматків зо два / Є хліба в торбині..." / Т. Шевченко "Великий льох"
> - "У мене є патент" / І. Франко "Украдене щастя"
> - "Коли ж в тебе є друга, то покажи, де вона, я їй, суцi, тут же очi видряпаю" / Квітка-Основ’яненко "Конотопська відьма"
> - "Я навiдаюся опiсля, бо у мене є дiло до Смоквинова" / І.Карпенко-Карий "Сто тисяч"
> - "В мене є другi... май лiпшi" / М.Коцюбинський "Тіні забутих предків"
> - "А тепер у мене є ще друге дiло" / Б. Лепкий "Мазепа"
> - "...у мене є одне щастя - ти" / М. Стельмах "Велика рідня"
> - "Та хлiба не жаль, i полотно ж у мене є" / А. Головко "Бур’ян"
> - "У мене є хлопець. Вiн тобi печiнки одiб'є. Геть вiд мене!" / В. Сосюра "Третя Рота"
> - "А воно в тебе є. О, я хоч i стара, й дурна, але дещо знаю. У смiливих щастя завжди є" / І.Багряний "Тигролови"
> - "І яка в нього є сука Флейта, як вона ганяє! По два мiсяцi вовка ганяла" /Остап Вишня "Мисливські усмішки"
> - "Сiм'я в мене є. П'ятеро синiв i дочка" / О.Довженко "Щоденник"
> - "А в мене є другий на примiтi" / Г. Тютюнник "Вир"
> - "Не питайте, хто Павловi
>   Булаву добуде,
>   Є у нього Україна,
>   Є у нього люди." / С.Руданський "Павло Полуботок"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).